# Rscript is plotting to PDF

Tags: r, scripting

I've a simple [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) script. When it is run via Rscript.exe, by default it is plotting to a PDF file. I want the script to open a plot window.

I using the command:

```
Rscript.exe tmp_plot.R
```

r file tmp_plot.R contains:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- sin(x)
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are running R in a non-interactive way - Rscript is meant for scripts - hence the default plotting device is `pdf()`, not `x11()` or whatever is your OS's default (`windows()` by the looks of it). It is trivial to open an alternative device, however; use `x11()` or `windows()`. The problem you have in trying to write a script that will display a plot on screen is that, in your example code shown, the script terminates immediately upon drawing the plot, whether displayed on screen or on the `pdf()` device. At best you might get it to pause using `Sys.sleep()`, e.g.:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- sin(x)
x11() ## or windows()
plot(x,y)
Sys.sleep(10)
```

I think you are going about this the wrong way. If you want interactivity when running an R "script", by which I mean a set of R statements that perform some analysis, you'd be better off getting an editor/IDE on your OS that allows you to step through the script a line or chunk of code at a time, plus interact with the running R session. I use Emacs and the ESS extension for this. You might consider Tinn-R or RStudio as alternatives.

`Rscript` is meant for running scripting or batch-like jobs that do not need human interaction or intervention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I am using RStudio. I wanted to "deploy" my r script on another machine as a standalone application using batch file. Is there anything similar to Matlab's deploytool?

Answer (score 6):

```
library(tcltk)  # for message box and thus hold-open functionality

x11()  # for Linux, see documentation for other operating systems

# first plot
# second plot

# hold-open functionality prevents script from exiting user acts
prompt  <- "hit spacebar to close plots"
extra   <- "some extra comment"
capture <- tk_messageBox(message = prompt, detail = extra)
```

If you don't like the idea of a prescribed timer, the above script will only exit on key press (the spacebar or enter) or mouse click (the OK button) from the user.

Comment: The Rscript developers might like to consider a --persist option, similar to that offered by [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info).

Answer (score 0):

Using windows, I worked around this issue by writing a batch script that calls Rscript on the script, then immediately opens the generated PDF.

```
@echo off
rscript myscript.r
Rplots.pdf
```

Although this solution is ridiculous, it is exactly what I needed, which is simply viewing the plotted data on the fly.