# Cannot insert plot into XLSX via openxlsx package when using command line

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, openxlsx

I'm trying to insert a plot into an XLSX file using the `openxlsx` package in R.
When I use the R GUI, I am able to accomplish this.

However, when using a batch file, the plot is created but it is not inserted into the XLSX file. Instead, it is created as a separate PDF file adjacent to the newly created XLSX file (automatically named "Rplots.pdf"). The data frame is written into the XLSX file just fine.

The R script (named "insertPlot.R"):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Data")
addWorksheet(wb, "Graph", gridLines=FALSE)
df <- data.frame(c(1:5), c(5:1))
names(df) <- c("x","y")
writeData(wb, "Data", df)
p <- ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + geom_line(size=1, colour="blue")
print(p)    #plot needs to be showing
insertPlot(wb, "Graph", width=11.18, height=7.82, fileType="png", units="in")
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite=TRUE)
```

The batch file script:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\RScript.exe" --no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole "C:\temp\insertPlot.R"
```

[image: R GUI (Desired) Result]

[image: R Batch Command Result]

In summary, I'm confused as to how to have an RScript batch file accomplish this.

Has anyone had any success or can point out my mistake?

Comment: After further digging, I believe I have found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024486/rscript-is-plotting-to-pdf). The key is to use `x11()` or `windows()` before running the plot to get this to work. However, this is not using Rscript in its designed way. Seems I need to go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe I have found a way to seamlessly accomplish this by outputting the plot to a `png` device and then utilizing `insertImage` from the `openxlsx` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Data")
addWorksheet(wb, "Graph", gridLines=FALSE)

df <- data.frame(c(1:5), c(5:1))
names(df) <- c("x","y")
writeData(wb, "Data", df)

png("graph.png", width=1024, height=768, units="px", res=144)  #output to png device
p <- ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) + geom_line(size=1, colour="blue")
print(p)
dev.off()  #important to shut down the active png device
insertImage(wb, "Graph", "graph.png", width=11.18, height=7.82, units="in")

saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite=TRUE)

#unlink("graph.png")  #can optionally delete the original png file
```

Hope this helps anyone that could be facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am new so any feedback would be appreciated:

For those looking for a Centos 7 answer using Xvfb (virtual X server environment):

install Xvfb

```
yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

when calling Rscript use xvfb-run -a to run the script within a virtual X server environment

```
xvfb-run -a Rscript /mnt/todd/examples/openxlsxChart.R
```

Add x11() to actual R file

```
library(openxlsx)
x11()
## Not run: 
## Create a new workbook
wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()

## Add a worksheet
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1", gridLines = FALSE) 

## create plot objects
require(ggplot2)
p1 <- qplot(mpg, data=mtcars, geom="density",
            fill=as.factor(gear), alpha=I(.5), main="Distribution of Gas Mileage")
p2 <- qplot(age, circumference,
            data = Orange, geom = c("point", "line"), colour = Tree)

## Insert currently displayed plot to sheet 1, row 1, column 1
#print(p1) #plot needs to be showing
print(p1)
insertPlot(wb, 1, width = 5, height = 3.5, fileType = "png", units = "in")

## Insert plot 2
print(p2)
insertPlot(wb, 1, xy = c("J", 2), width = 16, height = 10,  fileType = "png", units = "cm")

## Save workbook
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, "/home/tmamiya/insertPlotExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

## End(Not run)
```